# Does cassandra create snapshots when deleting column families

Tags: cassandra

Does cassandra create snapshots when deleting column families? I have observed cassandra creating snapshots when deleting column families? is it the standard behavior? Even if I delete CF do i still have to keep data in my disks? If So why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Cassandra will create a snapshot of a column family that you truncate or drop. It is a safety feature in case you inadvertently mass-delete data. If you do not need the snapshot, you can remove it via the nodetool. Or if you want to disable the feature all-together, set the property `auto_snapshot: false` in your `cassandra.yaml` file.